# How HashMap Sorting work if all the key's hashcode is same

Tags: java, hashmap

Sorry if this question is not clear. I have very limited knowledge about hashmap. This was the question which was asked to me in the interview.

If all objects return same hascode and If we use those objects as key to store in hashmap. How sorting works in this case?

My understanding was if hashcode are same then new entry will replace the old entry in the hashmap.

But when i searched to understand more about how hashmap works if the two objects hashcode is same, i foudn that both objects will be stored in the linked list form in the bucket.

But its not clear how sorting will work in this case. If we try to sort this hashpMap using TreeMap.

Please help me to understand this.

Below code stores more than one entry in the hashmap where all the objects hashcode is same.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Employee implements Comparable
{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public Employee(String name, int age)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return name + ": " + age;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode(){
       return 1;       
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o){
       if (!(o instanceof Employee))
             return false;
          Employee e = (Employee) o;
          return e.getName().equals(name) && e.getAge() == age;

   }

   String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   int getAge()
   {
      return age;
   }

   public static void main(String a[]){
       Employee e = new Employee("Sub" , 25);
       Employee e1 = new Employee("Sub1" , 20);
       Employee e2 = new Employee("Sub2" , 22);
       System.out.println(e);

       Map m = new HashMap();
       m.put(e , "A");
       m.put(e1 , "B");
       m.put(e2 , "C");

       System.out.println(m);

       TreeMap t = new TreeMap(m);

       System.out.println(t);

   }

@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    return ((Employee)arg0).getName().compareTo(this.name);
}
}
```

Comment: Sorting? `HashMap` doesn't do any sorting.

Comment: Yep, HashMap isn't sorted. From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): `This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map;`  You'll need to be more clear what you mean or your question will likely be closed

Answer (score 1):

Objects are distributed on the storage space according to the hash value obtained from their hashcode function. If all objects return the same hashcode, you'll have a collision for each object you add to the HashMap. Also you'll have a sequential search (using equals method) for every object you get from the Hashmap.

In short: change your hashcode algorithm to reduce collisions.

Comment: I am able to store more than one entry in the hashmap where all the object return same hashcode. Please refer my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add the same key but with different values I will recommend you to use MultiMap from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) or [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). I found it more useful because you can use ListMultimap ([Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)) and then it doesnt mather if you add the same key the values will be added to a list. I know this is not the question but I think you asked it because you have some issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

hashmap is not store elements in sorting order.
For storing it fisrt look for the appropriete bucket with the help of hashcode.

if hashcode are same it will store the element in linklist format and with utilization of single bucket only.